# What percentage of characters in normal English Literature is written in capitals?

Tags: capitalization

I'm talking about percentage of letters, not words, in case it isn't clear. Is there a way to gauge this?

Comment: I'd guess between one and three percent.

Comment: Hmm... maybe I just don't use proper nouns enough!  2.5% - 5% seems more like it, judging from JSBangs' answer.

Comment: What prompted this question, out of curiosity?

Comment: I saw my name coming up in chat stats at our university's DC server as the user who typed most in capitals. It was around 3% and I was wondering was it normal.

Comment: @Capt.Nemo Around 3% is normal for books with real sentences, but a lot of IM is either all lowercase or without initial capitals. You must have high standards!

Comment: Most of IM usernames are small words beginning in capitals and I tend to type them out exactly.

Comment: IMs are way different from 'normal English literature' -- the right thing to do was comparing with your peers in chat rooms as they did.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Between 2–4%, depending on the text and the genre.

To determine this, I downloaded a variety of texts from Project Gutenberg, then wrote a simple program to count the total number of alphabetic characters and the total number of capitalized characters in each file. Here are the raw numbers:

| *Title* (Author) | Letter Count | Caps Count | Percent Caps |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| *Pride and Prejudice* (Austen) | 2,641,527 | 14,177 | 2.56% |
| *History of the Decline and Fall of the Roman Empire* (Gibbon) | 1,295,410 | 34,893 | 2.69% |
| *Moby Dick* (Melville) | 968,516 | 28,204 | 2.91% |
| *Great Expectations* (Dickens) | 777,248 | 23,668 | 3.05% |
| *Shunned House* (Lovecraft) | 66,779 | 2,223 | 3.32% |
| *Tom Sawyer* (Twain) | 312,196 | 10,746 | 3.44% |
| *Somebody Comes to Town, Somebody Leaves Town* (Doctorow) | 495,594 | 17,366 | 3.50% |
| *Bible* (King James Version) | 3,343,105 | 117,344 | 3.51% |
| *Ulysses* (Joyce) | 1,203,807 | 55,244 | 4.58% |
| *Hamlet* (Shakespeare) | 139,132 | 7,812 | 5.61% |

*Hamlet* comes in with the highest percentage capitals, probably because it’s a script and the repeated character names are always capitalized. *Ulysses* is also unusually high, because Joyce is weird and uses lots of capitals in unexpected places. The other texts run from about 2.5% to 3.5%.

**Edit**: Added Melville, Lovecraft, Dickens, Doctorow to fill out the comparison of contemporary, early 20th century, and 19th century authors. I’m not seeing much of a trend here, with the most contemporary authors actually having a somewhat *higher* percentage of capitals than the earlier models. I suspect that more modern writers have shorter sentences, and therefore more sentence-initial capitalization, and that this effect swamps the effect of freer capitalization in earlier texts.

Comment: My gut feeling is that total percentage capitalisation would have been continuously declining over the last couple of centuries at least. 2% is probably the upper end of the scale for the last few decades, particularly if you exclude acronyms, of which I'm sure there are far more in common use nowadays.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, why would you exclude acronyms? Nothing in the question suggests that it would be desirable to do so.

Comment: No particular reason. Just making the point that if it *is* true that we use capitalised acronyms more often today, *and* if your simple program showed a lower percentage for more recent publications, that would imply the trend towards less capitalisation in "general" writing was even more marked. Although thinking about it I would guess average sentence length has probably fallen over time, which would go the other way.

Comment: Didn't Joyce also write a book that was all one sentence, or contained no punctuation?

Comment: Or maybe because Hamlet is in blank verse, where you have a capital letter at the beginning of every line.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming the Project Gutenberg etext of Herman Melville’s *Moby-Dick* is representative of all English literature:

- Uppercase letters: 24,559
- (Lowercase letters: 936,138)
- All characters: 1,231,937

24,559 / 1,231,937 = **2.00%** capitals letters (across all characters).

Or as a percentage of letters (ignoring non-letter characters):

- Uppercase letters: 24,559
- (Lowercase letters: 936,138)
- All letters: 960,737

24,559 / 960,737 = **2.56%** capital letters (across all letters).

---

Edit 2: Taking this a step further, I ran a script on the plain text ebooks from [Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/wiki/Gutenberg:The_CD_and_DVD_Project)’s CD and DVDs:

| Source | Caps | Letters | Pct Caps | Characters | Pct Caps |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| *Moby-Dick*: 1 ebook | 24,559 | 960,737 | 2.56% | 1,231,937 | 2.00% |
| 2003 CD: 594 ebooks | 11,407,295 | 319,286,662 | 3.57% | 417,687,793 | 2.73% |
| 2006 DVD: 16,536 ebooks | 179,318,621 | 4,913,640,039 | 3.65% | 6,380,437,180 | 2.81% |
| 2010 DVD: 14,792 ebooks | 152,637,904 | 4,102,894,980 | 3.72% | 5,433,866,318 | 2.81% |
| Total: 31,923 ebooks | 343,388,379 | 9,336,782,418 | 3.68% | 12,233,223,228 | 2.81% |

The median values are 3.72% and 2.85%, and mode values are 3.12% and 2.29%.